# Basic Gulp Uglify Setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to take all `.js` files in my project, and for each, save a minified version in the same directory.

That is, given this project directory structure:

```
project/
    gulpfile.js
    basic.js
    Project/
        Project.js
        Toolbelt.js
        Colors/
            RGBA.js
            HSLA.js
```

My gulpfile should create these minified files:

```
project/
    basic.js
    basic.min.js // ADDED BY GULP
    Project/
        Project.js
        Project.min.js // ADDED BY GULP
        Toolbelt.js
        Toolbelt.min.js // ADDED BY GULP
        Colors/
            RGBA.js
            RGBA.min.js // ADDED BY GULP
            HSLA.js
            HSLA.min.js // ADDED BY GULP
```

These seems like it should be relatively straightforward, but I seem to have missed it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it only seems to work on `basic.js` (`basic.min.js` is created successfully), but it's not working for any files within folders. I'm not sure if `**.js` isn't working as I'm expecting, or `gulp.dest('')` isn't pointing to the current file's directory.. I've done some experimenting off this, and I'm stumped.

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('js-minify', function(){
    return gulp.src(['**.js', '!gulpfile.js', '!**.min.js'])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename(function(path){
            path.extname = '.min.js';
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});
```

Running `gulp js-minify` from the command line does not yield the results I'm looking for.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is your `gulp.src` paths, you're not looking in directories:

```
['**/*.js', '!gulpfile.js', '!**/*.min.js']
```